# Change to Static IP address but Internet not working

Tags: networking, wifi, internet, static-ip

i set up a static ip address on my pi 3 but after that the internet is not working. how can I change it to dynamic? or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Set a 'reserved' ip address in your DHCP (router) server: It will always assign the same IP address to your Pi. It will act the same as a static address. No configuration in the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the configuration file /etc/networl/interfaces.

for eth0 you must have a row like this one

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

change the file, saveit and restart network service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

you can renew your ip address with dhclient

Of course you must have root privileges. Use `su - root` or `sudo`